# NextJs wrong redirection

Tags: next.js

When i try to go on my connection or subscription page on production mode i get this error in my console and also url of the page isnt the one i set in my code. It works fine in localhost.

```
framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom' of null
at h (compte.js:1)
at Gi (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at ko (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at xu (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at wu (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at du (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1
at t.unstable_runWithPriority (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at $l (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at Xl (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)

main-b8de2659c8e469d623b1.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom' of null
at h (compte.js:1)
at Gi (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at ko (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at xu (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at wu (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at du (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1
at t.unstable_runWithPriority (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at $l (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
at Xl (framework.79fb030ec3df0dc442a2.js:1)
```

i understand my user is not defined yet since nobody is connected or subscribed but the problem is that Next doesnt redirect to where it should :

my code :

```
       <Link passHref href='/register'>
           <li>
             <a>S'inscrire</a>
           </li> 
        </Link> 
        <Link passHref href='/login'>
           <li>
             <a>Se connecter</a>
           </li>
         </Link>
```

And it sends me to /compte whenever i try to click on one of those links in production.

Screenshots :
https://res.cloudinary.com/dzqfghzga/image/upload/v1599828198/xpbob6lwdz9ir3ozmiba.jpg

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

-Go to 'https://sungym69.com/'
-Click on 's'inscrir' or 'Se connecter' in navbar
-See error

thx for your help

Comment: I am not seeing the error, was it fixed?

Comment: Not fixed yet , but might be chrome related it works just fine on Edge and safari

Comment: Tried on Chrome version 85

Comment: i have this one too Version 85.0.4183.102 (Build officiel) (64 bits)             Ok found solution, was a cache issue with chrome i reset it and now it works.